# Part compatibility

Tags: axle, drive-shaft

I need to change the Right hand drive shaft of a 2010 nissan juke, i looked up the part number online and found it,

the part that is online is slightly different in looks to the original in the car,

the one in my car has a bracket like mound in one side, highlighted in red, but the one i am about to purchase doesn't have the highlighted part, can you have a look and let me know if the difference doesn't matter. Both pictures attached.

Below is the original shaft in my car

[image]

And here is the shaft from a parts website online
[image]

and here is the part number from parts souq

[image]

Comment: The image with the part numberis the left hand axle. If you are sitting in the front seat facing the windshield your right is the vehicles right. Make sure your searching for the correct side axle.